# Swift JSONDecoder - Coding Keys not working with underscore

Tags: ios, json, swift, decoding, codable

Can someone please explain why code in part A works, and B does not please. It has me baffled.

**WORKING**

```
struct Coded : Codable, Hashable {  
  public let avar1: String
  public let avar2: String

  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case avar1 = "avar1"
    case avar2 = "avar2"
  }

  init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    print (container.allKeys)
    avar1 = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .avar1)
    avar2 = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .avar2)
  }
}

let JSONStr = """
{
  "avar1": "This is a string",
  "avar2": "This is a string2",
}
"""

if let jsdata = JSONStr.data(using: .utf8) {
  let decoder = JSONDecoder()
  decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
  let aobj: Coded? = try? decoder.decode(Coded.self, from: jsdata)
  print (aobj ?? "No object")
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[CodingKeys(stringValue: "avar1", intValue: nil), CodingKeys(stringValue: "avar2", intValue: nil)]
Coded(avar1: "This is a string", avar2: "This is a string2")
```

**NOT WORKING**

```
struct Coded : Codable, Hashable {  
  public let avar1: String
  public let avar2: String

  enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case avar1 = "avar1"
    case avar2 = "avar_2"
  }

  init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    print (container.allKeys)
    avar1 = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .avar1)
    avar2 = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .avar2)
  }
}

let JSONStr = """
{
  "avar1": "This is a string",
  "avar_2": "This is a string2",
}
"""

if let jsdata = JSONStr.data(using: .utf8) {
  let decoder = JSONDecoder()
  decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
  let aobj: Coded? = try? decoder.decode(Coded.self, from: jsdata)
  print (aobj ?? "No object")
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
[CodingKeys(stringValue: "avar1", intValue: nil)]
No object
```

The second function will only show the coding key *without* the underscore. But as soon as I remove the underscore it has the coding key in allKeys...

Swift 4.2 - Xcode 10.2.

Any ideas?

Comment: I finally got this working after closing my playground and starting it again. It looks like it could be an interpreter issue... It's extremely strange.

Comment: It looks like the larger data sets were using the .convertFromSnakeCase which caused the coding keys to disappear during decode.

Answer (score 4):

`.convertFromSnakeCase` converts *snake_cased* variables to *camelCase* **before** accessing the `CodingKeys`.

If you want to specify `CodingKeys` you have to use the converted value in your *NOT WORKING* example

```
enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case avar1 = "avar1"
    case avar2 = "avar2"
}
```

But this illustrates the pointlessness of the `CodingKeys`. So think the other way round and take advantage of the key decoding strategy.

Rather than removing `.convertFromSnakeCase` remove the `CodingKeys` and the initializer.

**And catch always possible `Decoding` errors.**

```
struct Coded : Codable {
    public let avar1: String
    public let avar2: String
}

let jsonStr = """
{
"avar1": "This is a string",
"avar_2": "This is a string2",
}
"""

let jsdata = Data(jsonStr.utf8)
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
do {
    let aobj = try decoder.decode(Coded.self, from: jsdata)
    print(aobj)
} catch { print(error) }
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing the insight that the keys are converted to camel case before accessing the coding keys. My personal preference would to remove the convertFromSnakeCase, because using it obfuscated the binding relationship of the keys to the variable names in JSON.

Answer (score 2):

I have fixed this issue. It stems from a problem that occurs with Snake Case. In some situations in may cause problems. What they are an why they happen, I am not sure. But if you have a JSONDecoder with the Snake Case Startegy enabled. It will remove KeyCodings for items that are coded using snake case.

By removing the following from my JSONDecoder I was able to fix the problem.

Please remove the following and force Coding Strings into snake case, if you have this parameter set and force your JSONDecoder strategy with .convertFromSnakeCase it will remove the the Coding Key strings and will break during decoding.

If your coding keys include

```
codingKey = "a_json_var"
```

If you add convertFromSnakeCase, this will remove the coding key altogether. So, do not specify a text string on your coding key case in snake case, otherwise it will break.

Remove ->

```
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
```

If you want to specify the exact coding key text name correctly.